# Handling POST request with axios and express

Tags: javascript, express, axios

I can't seem to figure out why when I'm doing an axios.post method providing a body of data, it gets captured as undefined on my server.

I have the following files with snippets of code:

app.js:

```
auth(user, pass){
    return axios.post('http://localhost:3000/auth', {
        username: user, 
        password: pass
    })
}
```

server.js:

```
app.post('/auth', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body) //undefined
    res.end("Success")  
})
```

I'm how can I properly handle the POST data using axios?  Am I missing something?

The success returns fine, but the username / password cannot seem to be found anywhere in the req

Comment: are you using middleware in express before any request handlers to handle xhr requests?

like:

`app.use('/*', function(req,res,next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
  next();
});`

Comment: Ah, yes, it seems it uses webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-hot-middleware.  Though i don't believe those would affect the POST handling .  I might need to dig in further since I am using a [boilerplate](https://github.com/choonkending/react-webpack-node)

Comment: Actually, seems like it's also using bodyParser to handle the POST requests.

Comment: Turns out I had all my middleware installed out of order;  I was attempting to handle the POST in my server.js file prior to using any middleware.  Thanks for the middleware tip! You're the bomb!

Answer (score 19):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on Jim's last post but I had the same problem and that solved it!

To clarify: In my server.js file I was requiring my routes before these:

these first:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
```

then this:

```
app.use(routes);
```

Answer (score 8):

Add following parser to handle the requested data

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: Solved a similar problem for me

Answer (score 4):

Turns out I had all my middleware installed out of order; I was attempting to handle the POST in my server.js file prior to using any middleware.

Comment: I am having a similar problem but don't understand how you solved it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  For my situation, I had to ensure that express handled all the middleware prior to setting up any routes.  So be sure that you set up all your app.use([middleware]) configurations get run prior to running any GET or POST routes